# How to use ElasticSearch for product search (filtering) in eShop?

Tags: mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, search

I'm new in ElasticSearch!
I have an eShop (using Laravel) with more than 1,000,000 products and each product has some properties in `product` table like name, description, price , ... and some other properties in other tables like `categories`, `options`, `tags`, `addresses`, `rating`, `brands`, ... which are in separated tables and they will join to products by `many-to-many` relationships!

so I want to have a very fast and reliable search for products with many filters! like amzon! for example user would be able to find products with special categories, tags, options , ...! as you now in mysql I have to multiple use something like `WHERE EXISTS`, `INNER JOIN` and  ... and since the products number is too big these queries are so costly and slow! so I've found that elastic search has a solution for this situation! it loves to work with big data!

I've read about it! now I have an idea but I'm not sure is it a correct way?

I say we can store each `categories`, `options`, `tags`, `addresses`, `rating`, `brands` as a json object in elastic search just on each **UPDATE/STORE** event in the laravel appilication! in mysql they have separated tables and their many-to-many relationships! but we don't have to define an index for each of them (tables) and repeat to join them in elastic again same as mysql way!

in elastic search we will have this pattern for products:

```
"id" : 782,
"title" : "dmorar",
"price" : "11000.00",
"options" : [ the ids of the product's tags ],
"categories" : [ the ids of the product's categories],
"tags" : [ the ids of the product's tags ],
"addresses" : [ the ids of the product's addresses]
```

this is an example:

```
  {
    "_index" : "so_product",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1099",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : 782,
      "title" : "dmorar",
      "price" : "11000.00",
      "created_at" : "2020-07-30T14:01:09.000000Z",
      "updated_at" : "2020-07-30T14:01:09.000000Z",
      "options" : [
        75,
        955,
        480,
        351,
        285
      ],
      "categories" : [
        944,
        421
      ],
      "tags" : [
        210,
        198,
        648,
        976,
        10,
        553,
        624,
        967,
        726,
        121,
        797
      ],
      "addresses" : [
        119,
        43,
        140,
        1713,
        855,
        1515,
        958
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "so_product",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1344",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : 429,
      "title" : "ethyl.wehner",
      "price" : "89000.00",
      "created_at" : "2020-07-30T13:59:02.000000Z",
      "updated_at" : "2020-07-30T13:59:02.000000Z",
      "options" : [
        121,
        195,
        348
      ],
      "categories" : [
        372,
        315,
        869,
        544,
        645,
        803,
        564
      ],
      "tags" : [
        347,
        797
      ],
      "addresses" : [
        609,
        1477,
        187,
        1479
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "so_product",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1370",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : 358,
      "title" : "cicero.casper",
      "price" : "67000.00",
      "created_at" : "2020-07-30T13:58:37.000000Z",
      "updated_at" : "2020-07-30T13:58:37.000000Z",
      "options" : [
        665,
        28,
        488,
        384,
        547,
        877
      ],
      "categories" : [
        508,
        201
      ],
      "tags" : [
        325,
        472,
        595,
        797,
        943,
        948,
        803,
        136,
        288,
        275,
        574,
        390
      ],
      "addresses" : [
        691,
        1637,
        534,
        770,
        499,
        1086,
        430,
        1365,
        1325
      ]
    }
  }
```

Buy this way a search query like this can give a full control to user to use each filter which he wants and it is fast:

```
GET so_product/_search
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
            "term": {
            "options": 5
            }
        }, 
        {
            "term": {
            "options": 695
            }
        } ,
        {
            "term": {
            "categories": 523
            }
        }
         ,
        {
            "term": {
            "addresses": 116
            }
        } 
        ,
        {
            "term": {
            "tags": 797
            }
        } 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But as I said before I'm not sure this is the correct way or not? if it is not correct what is the standard way? how does amazon implement this search filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ES schema is ok, but you can improve it by replacing IDs (like tag IDs, category IDs and etc) with their actual values. In this way, you can get your sidebar filters and facets from ElasticSearch based on the query that has been entered, plus you can retrieve it so much faster than fetching them from MySQL.

Since you are using Laravel, you can use events for when a product is created, updated or any properties like categories, tags, and ... is added to products to reflect the changes to elastic search.

Comment: For faceted search, UI mostly do have both id's & values. So in that particular case faceted search can also be powered by id's. Adding values also adds cost of updating category, tags, etc when one is changed. I will advice to refrain from using names unless required.

Answer (score 2):

**My Observation:**

Elastic Search is a great tool for :

1. Search
2. Real-time aggregation

**Points to Note:**

1. Use it if eventual consistency is ok. E.g Indexed documents may not be immediately available for search
2. Store the data required for search in a denormalized format.
3. ES has some nuances e.g Number of primary shards can't be increased, make sure to have a value that works for you.

**Your use case:**

1. Mysql is not serving your application well for search (with the data you have).

   - ES is a good option for search
2. Your schema looks good. Make sure to explicitly define index mapping.